# Listen to API response using angular-file-upload module

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-file-upload

I'm building a WebApp using AngulasJs and Django and I'm currently relying on angular-file-upload to upload image to my api like so :

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({ 
                   url: 'http://localhost:8000/image', 
                   headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value')
                            }, 
               });
```

The files is uploaded fine but then what I have been unable to figure out is how to get the response from the api (Some data that I need to insert into my html). I first supposed I would be able to register some kind of listener using angular-file-upload module but I didn't find anything that could allow me to do that.

Does the angular-file-upload module provide a way to do this or do I need to rely on an other angularjs functionality ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [angular-file-upload-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-upload-shim), you could declare callback functions like this:

```
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    url: 'rs/medias/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    file: file 
}).progress(function (evt) {
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering.

I may not understand your response but it seems to me that such callbacks are not available to me when using angular-file-upload.

According to the documentation of angular-file-upload https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API there are no callbacks defined to get api answer on success. The callbacks are triggered either when the the upload is completed or failed but not when the response of the api arrive.

I guess I could use an other way than with angular-file-upload but since I started with it I would prefer to continue with it if a way exist.

Comment: I've clarified my answer. Actually my example is using angular-file-upload-shim with angular-file-upload

Comment: It seem that angular-file-upload-shim is actually relying on ng-file-upload module and not angular-file-upload module. the documentation is confusing because they switch between the two name. but looking at the code of their demo they load ng-file-upload.js and not angular-file-upload.js...

Comment: You're right. I've just noticed that this project I use had been renamed from angular-file-upload to ng-file-upload, as described in description [here](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-file-upload)

Comment: Ok. I think I'm gonna switch of module then. Thanks for the help